# Printing a PNG file at an accurate size

Tags: printing

I have to print something to an exact size (precision to within a mm). I have written some python code to create the image, but when I try to print the size is completely wrong.

I am trying to print at **A4 600DPI**, which I found out should be **4960 x 7016 pixels**. If I test the image I created through `.shape` it shows the PNG image is `7016 rows by 4960 columns`. The printer is set to **A4, 600DPI**, print size 'Original Size (from image DPI)'.

Does anyone have an idea why the printing is coming out at such a strange size? It is not close, I can see maybe 1 percent of the top left of the image I am trying to print.

Comment: It might help to say if you are printing from a HTML doc, a PDF, or directly from your python etc

Comment: I was saving an image as a PNG file from python, then opening it in InfranView. I printed it off within the print options from InfranView.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with this. I just suggested the extra info for others to see. If there is a tag for InfranView add that. Alternatively, I had a similar issue printing labels from the web, worked on my printer but not on client's. Sent output to PDF instead of HTML/CSS and it worked.